# Output html from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got this html select which is empty, I want the html to be included from js file, but it's simply not injecting... check it out

```
<select id="province" name="province"></select>

$("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()=="canada") {

                $('#province').innerHTML = '<option value="">Please select your province...</option>';

                console.log('Canada baby!');
            }
        });
    }).change();
```

Comment: Is the DOM loaded at the time of injecting?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, if the select is empty, change will not be triggered

Comment: you mean by wrapping the function in a .ready ? Then yesss

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla He’s got a `.change()` at the end though which should work in jQuery. I think the main issue is that there’s no `$("select option:selected")`, thus there’s nothing to iterate over. Except if there are other `select` elements… I don’t know about that.

Comment: But even if there are multiple `select`s, `$(this).val()=="canada"` can never be true as far as I know because there is no `value` from a selected `option` because there is no `option`.

Comment: So is your goal to inject **only**  `<option value="">Please select your province...</option>`? and basically to 'reset' the select?

Comment: @user2421594 Oh, I forgot that you bind the listener to `$("select")` and not `$("#province")`… Can you provide us the other `select`s as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you need two select lists.
One for country and one for province in case Canada is selected.

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<div id="state"></div>

$(function(){
$("#country option").click(function(){

        $(this).each(function(){
            if($(this).val()=="canada") {
                $("#state").html('<select id="province" name="province"><option value="">Please select your province...</option></select>');
                console.log('Canada baby!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qcmfwqjo/